# How to insert a newline between different multiplication tables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, newline, multiplication

I wrote this code to print out the multiplication table from 1 to 9, but it prints it out without a new line between the different tables. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        k = i * j
        print(i,"x",j, "=", k)
```

the result is this:

```
1 x 1 = 1
1 x 2 = 2
1 x 3 = 3
1 x 4 = 4
1 x 5 = 5
1 x 6 = 6
1 x 7 = 7
1 x 8 = 8
1 x 9 = 9
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
2 x 3 = 6
2 x 4 = 8
2 x 5 = 10
2 x 6 = 12
2 x 7 = 14
2 x 8 = 16
2 x 9 = 18
```

Answer (score 2):

Print an empty line between iterations of your `for i in range(1, 10):` loop, this will separate the tables by the number you're printing the multiplication of

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        k = i * j
        print(i,"x",j, "=", k)
    print()

>> 1 x 1 = 1
>> 1 x 2 = 2
>> 1 x 3 = 3

>> 2 x 1 = 2
>> 2 x 2 = 4
>> 2 x 3 = 6

>> 3 x 1 = 3
>> 3 x 2 = 6
>> 3 x 3 = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        k = i * j
        print(i,"x",j, "=", k, end='\n')
```